# K-means Clustering of text data : Get which cluster does the text belong to

Tags: python, scikit-learn, cluster-analysis, nltk, k-means

I am clustering textual data using K-Means in Python(scikit-learn).
How do I get the cluster to which the line belongs?

Example :
data=["Red , Yellow and Blue are colours","Icecream is my favourite food","You can now get icecream in strawberry flavour too","Sky is blue"]

After performing K-Means with n_clusters=2, I expect two clusters to be formed s.t.

"Red , Yellow and Blue are colours","Sky is blue" lie in one cluster and "Icecream is my favourite food","You can now get icecream in strawberry flavour too" lie in the other.

How do I get this i.e. which line is in which cluster?

Code for K-means :

```
vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer(stop_words='english')
X = vectorizer.fit_transform(data)
model = KMeans(n_clusters=true_k, init='k-means++', max_iter=500,  n_init=20)
model.fit(X)
```

Answer (score 2):

Try using the `predict` function.

Example -

```
model.predict(X)
```

From [documentation](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.cluster.KMeans.html#sklearn.cluster.KMeans.predict) -

> predict(X)
>
> Predict the closest cluster each sample in X belongs to.
>
> In the vector quantization literature, cluster_centers_ is called the code book and each value returned by predict is the index of the closest code in the code book.
>
> Parameters:
>   X : {array-like, sparse matrix}, shape = [n_samples, n_features]
>   New data to predict.
>
> Returns:
>   labels : array, shape [n_samples,]
>   Index of the cluster each sample belongs to.

This seems to return the array of indexes of cluster each sample belongs to.

Maybe you can also use - [`fit_predict()`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.cluster.KMeans.html#sklearn.cluster.KMeans.fit_predict) function.

You can get cluster centers using the attribute - `cluster_centers_` , in your case - `model.cluster_centers_` and the label for each sample - `model.labels_` .